# Firebase attaching listener to a Query object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) it's a bad practice to attach a listener to a high level in Database hierarchy. I have a high level field called "places" (very large) and I'm getting a reference to it. But when I'm going to attach the listener (ChildEventListener) I'm using

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference placesReference = database.getReference("places");
placesReference.orderByChild("city").equalsTo("Madrid").addChildEventListener(....)
```

to only retrieve places in that city.

My question is - if the listener is attached to only places with

```
city = "Madrid"
```

or is attached to the entire places level hierarchy and therefore a bad practice.

**EDIT**

This is my Database

```
[...]
"places" : {
  "SomePlaceID_1" : {
      "address" : "Some address",
      "city" : "Madrid",
      "coord_latitude" : 12.122121,
      "coord_longitude" : 12.122121
  },
  "SomePlaceID_2" : {
      "address" : "Some address",
      "city" : "Madrid",
      "coord_latitude" : 12.122121,
      "coord_longitude" : 12.122121
  },
  "SomePlaceID_3" : {
      "address" : "Some address",
      "city" : "Barcelona",
      "coord_latitude" : 12.122121,
      "coord_longitude" : 12.122121
  },
  [...]
},
[...]
```

So, it is attached to all places or just the places with *city : "Madrid"*?

Comment: Why are you using `.orderBy("city").equalsTo("Madrid")` if you have only one city and you don't have anything else to order?

Comment: You are using orderByChild aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `placesReference.orderBy("city").equalsTo("Madrid")` means that your reference is set on `placesReference`. If you have in your database only one city named Madrid, you don't need to use `orderBy()` method, you only need to use this line of code:

```
placesReference.child("city").child("Madrid").addChildEventListener(....)
```

which is definitely correct because you are now 2 steps down in the hierarchical tree. So in this case, you are only getting data from your Madrid node.

**Edit:**

Seeing your database after your edit, i can say that the way in which you have added the listener is very correct. This is the way in which you can achieve this using the current database structure. Remember, the listener is attached on the exact reference where you put it. In this case is attached to all the places (SomePlaceID_1, SomePlaceID_2 and so on), not only at those particular which have a child that have the value of "Madrid". Using `.orderByChild("city").equalsTo("Madrid")` is just an order. Using this order equalsTo("Madrid") on a value, does not mean that the listener is set there. In the example explained above, the listener is put 2 steps down in the three.

The solution in your case is to flatten your database. This means that you need to add another node in which you can add only those places from Madrid. Than add a listener only on that particular node.

I recomand you reading this post, [Structuring your Firebase Data correctly for a Complex App](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data) for a better understanding.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it's only attached where you put the listener is. Let's say below are my database.

```
{
  "places": {
    "a": {
      "city": "Madrid"
    },
    "b": {
      "city": "Madrid"
    },
    "c": {
      "city": "SomeCity"
    }
  }
}
```

Let's if you attached the listener like this.

```
placesReference.child("places").orderByChild("city").equalsTo("Madrid")
         .addChildEventListener(....)
```

Then the dataSnapshot will return like below

```
{
    "a": {
      "city": "Madrid"
    },
    "b": {
      "city": "Madrid"
    }
}
```

So the answer to your question is **NO**. The listener will not attached to the entire level of hierarchy if you used it this way.

**UPDATE:**

**Your question:** So, it is attached to all places or just the places with city : "Madrid"?

**My answer:** It is only attached to `SomePlaceID_1` an `SomePlaceID_2` only because they are the only child node that have `child("city")` value equals to `"Madrid"`.

```
  "SomePlaceID_1" : {
      "address" : "Some address",
      "city" : "Madrid",
      "coord_latitude" : 12.122121,
      "coord_longitude" : 12.122121
  },
  "SomePlaceID_2" : {
      "address" : "Some address",
      "city" : "Madrid",
      "coord_latitude" : 12.122121,
      "coord_longitude" : 12.122121
  }
```

Let's say you change `SomePlaceID_3` address to `"Another address"`. The listener will not be affected.

Comment: See my edit: if I change SomePlaceID_3 (which isn't in Madrid), the listener would be launch but no execute because *city not equal Madrid* or the listener not being launch at all cause is not attached to SomePlaceID_3?

Comment: @jorge If you change SomePlaceID_3, the listener will not launch at all because it is not attached to SomePlaceID_3 in the first place. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry but I think the other answer is correct since orderBy().equalsTo() it's just an order cause those methods retrieve a Query object, and the listener is attached to the DatabaseReference object in that Query retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

for example the root reference is "countriers"

and you wants to calculate the type city where it is madrid or something you wants

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Countries");
    databaseReference.limitToFirst(5);

    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("city").equalTo("Madrid");

    ChildEventListener removedListener = query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

              long  count=  dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                long  count=  dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                long  count=  dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```